# If referencing constant character strings with pointers, is memory permanently occupied?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm trying to understand where things are stored in memory (stack/heap, are there others?) when running a c program. Compiling this gives warning: function return adress of local variable:

```
char *giveString (void)
{
    char string[] = "Test";
    return string;
}
int main (void)
{
    char *string = giveString ();
    printf ("%s\n", string);
}
```

Running gives various results, it just prints jibberish. I gather from this that the char array called string in giveString() is stored in the stack frame of the giveString() function while it is running. But if I change the type of string in giveString() from char array to char pointer:

```
char *string = "Test";
```

I get no warnings, and the program prints out "Test". So does this mean that the character string "Test" is now located on the heap? It certainly doesn't seem to be in the stack frame of giveString() anymore. What exactly is going on in each of these two cases? And if this character string is located on the heap, so all parts of the program can access it through a pointer, will it never be deallocated before the program terminates? Or would the memory space be freed up if there was no pointers pointing to it, like if I hadn't returned the pointer to main? (But that is only possible with a garbage collector like in Java, right?) Is this a special case of heap allocation that is only applicable to pointers to constant character strings (hardcoded strings)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what the following statements do.

```
char string[] = "Test";
```

This code means: create an array in the local stack frame of sufficient size and copy the contents of constant string "Test" into it.

```
char *string = "Test";
```

This code means: set the pointer to point to constant string "Test".

In both cases, "Test" is in the `const` or `cstring` segment of your binary, where non-modifiable data exists.  It is neither in the heap nor stack.  In the former case, you're making a copy of "Test" that you can modify, but that copy disappears once your function returns.  In the latter case, you are merely pointing to it, so you can use it once your function returns, but you can never modify it.

You can think of the actual string "Test" as being global and always there in memory, but the concept of allocation and deallocation is not generally applicable to const data.

Answer (score 0):

No. The string `"Test"` is still on the stack, it's just in the `data` portion of the stack which basically gets set up before the program runs. It's there, but you can think of it kind of like "global" data.

The following may clear it up a tad for you:

```
char string[] = "Test"; // declare a local array, and copy "Test" into it
char* string = "Test";  // declare a local pointer and point it at the "Test"
                        // string in the data section of the stack
```

Comment: The constant string would not be put on the stack - most compilers would put it in the read only code section though in the past lots of compilers would put it in the initialised data section. And what is the "data section" of the stack?

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the second case you are creating a constant string :

```
char *string = "Test";
```

The value pointed by string is a constant and can never change, so it's allocated at compile time like a static variable(but it's still stack not heap).